# Why are bundle product tier prices a percent value?

Tags: price, bundled-product, tierprice, architecture

My question is not a coding but architectural one.

So for simple products, downloadable, grouped and configurable products the tier pricing uses a monetary value for for each price e.g. `20.59` in what ever currency you are using.

When you start to work with bundle products you see that the tier price is using a percentage discount on the product's base price.

Does anyone know the reasoning behind this?

Comment: never actually used bundle products, but they look quite hard to use. Do they have a price or, like the configurable products, they use their "sub-product"'s prices? Interesting question btw

Comment: @JulienLachal they can have either a fixed price and then the options can add to this price, or they can have a dynamic price where the price is built from the options.

Comment: Ha. Nice one. I might add that the group price and the special price use percentage, but not the `Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price`. That's still in currency units.

Comment: @Marius I only noticed cause I blindly imported some data and was seeing some odd results, but only on bundle products.

Comment: I've noticed this a really long time ago, but didn't question it. and in the mean time I forgot about it. Let me just grab my shovel and I'll start digging. It makes sense for dynamic priced bundles but for fixed price....

Comment: @Marius it is not a reason but the bundle product indexer will only work with a percentage and it also has a hard coded rounding to 2 decimal places ;)

Comment: the 2 decimal hardcoding is everywhere, I had to switch to 5 decimals for a client, it was such a pain, and ugly aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is, because the price of the bundle product is generated from the simple items you choose, therefore it is most of the time not possible to get ONE price which is used for all combinations.

Comment: For dynamic pricing this makes sense but you can also do fixed pricing. I guess in this case you would not want two different tier price settings.

Comment: Right but then you have to problem to do both in the frontend, I think this should be avoided.

Comment: Makes sense just a bit confusing when I was importing.

Comment: ah, bad thing. I would have ran into it too :(

Comment: Also didnt help cause our prices where > 1€ so we did not see the percentage early on